# Difference between mean and fitted in forecast function

Tags: r, forecasting

I'm new to forecasting and I'm trying to use the forecast package in r.

Can someone please explain the difference between mean and fitted in the forecast function?

For example,

```
fcast<-forecast(ts,h=30)

fcast$mean

fcast$fitted
```

The documentation says "mean is Point forecasts as a time series" 
and "fitted is Fitted values (one-step forecasts)".

An example to illustrate the difference would be great.  Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I'd say the fitted values are the estimated values for the past data used to build the model (with residuals beeing the offsets to the real values), and mean is the point forecast for future values in between the confidence boundaries.

Comment: `fcast$fitted` is the result of the fit (the model fitted to observation) and `fcast$mean` is the result of the forecast (the application of the model to the future). You can compare `length(ts)` and `length(fcast$fitted)`. And `length(fcast$mean)` and the `h` you choose.

Comment: But how do we know how much data the `forecast()` function used to train on if we don't specify it?

Answer (score 5):

`fcast$fitted` is the result of the fit (the model fitted to observation) and `fcast$mean` is the result of the forecast (the application of the model to the future). You can compare `length(ts)` and `length(fcast$fitted)`. And `length(fcast$mean)` and the `h` you choose.

```
library(forecast)
fit <- Arima(WWWusage,order=c(3,1,0))
h <- 20
fcast <- forecast(fit, h = h)

length(WWWusage)
# [1] 100

length(fcast$fitted)
# [1] 100

h
# [1] 20

length(fcast$mean)
# [1] 20
```

Comment: Thank you!  That answer is very helpful.