# forecast::ets, auto.arima offset by one

Tags: r, forecasting, forecast

I'm not sure if this is intended behaviour. Consider the following snippet of code -

```
library(forecast)
x <- c(
  0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00217764964493354, 0.00339032724317772, 0.00357374918778428, 
  0.00282328811130057, 0.00272679331678393, 0.0030360769697858, 
  0.00316665914235777, 0.00163300219677676, 0.00249817841157489, 
  0.00207838479809976, 0.00192104504850639, 0.00209700948212983, 
  0.00216356555603635, 0.00250983016815862, 0.0017474879860201
)
tsData <- ts(data = x, start = 2000, frequency = 1)
df <- data.frame(
  x = x, 
  fittedets = fitted(forecast(ets(tsData), h = 7)), 
  fittedarima = fitted(forecast(auto.arima(tsData), h = 7))
)
df

             x     fittedets fittedarima
1  0.000000000 -6.997521e-07 0.000000000
2  0.000000000 -7.065016e-11 0.000000000
3  0.000000000 -7.133162e-15 0.000000000
4  0.000000000 -7.201966e-19 0.000000000
5  0.002177650  0.000000e+00 0.000000000
6  0.003390327  2.177430e-03 0.002007587
7  0.003573749  3.390205e-03 0.003125561
8  0.002823288  3.573731e-03 0.003294659
9  0.002726793  2.823364e-03 0.002602805
10 0.003036077  2.726803e-03 0.002513846
11 0.003166659  3.036046e-03 0.002798976
12 0.001633002  3.166646e-03 0.002919360
13 0.002498178  1.633157e-03 0.001505474
14 0.002078385  2.498091e-03 0.002303084
15 0.001921045  2.078427e-03 0.001916074
16 0.002097009  1.921061e-03 0.001771022
17 0.002163566  2.096992e-03 0.001933245
18 0.002509830  2.163559e-03 0.001994603
19 0.001747488  2.509795e-03 0.002313826
```

The actual values are 0 until the fifth value, while in case of both models, the fitted values are about 0 until the sixth value.

I would assume them to be approximately 0 for the first five values, like the `x` column. Am I missing something basic?

Comment: The forecast is made on the known information up to that point, meaning that the prediction for the fifth value are made using the first four observations (well, depending on the chosen model ofc). Since the historical data is 0 until then, there will be no trend. If there is also no intercept, the prediction is 0 as well.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!

Comment: have a look at this post this will help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35448610/difference-between-mean-and-fitted-in-forecast-function

Answer (score 0):

It also has to do with the ARIMA model that `auto.arima` is fitting to your data. If you look at the model that it's being fitted:

```
Series: tsData 
ARIMA(1,0,0) with zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1
      0.9219
s.e.  0.0638

sigma^2 estimated as 6.076e-07:  log likelihood=108.59
AIC=-213.17   AICc=-212.42   BIC=-211.28
```

Remember that ARIMA stands for Autoregressive Integrated Moving Average, and the output tells us that only the AR part of the model was fitted, which makes it an AR(1) model:

y[t] = c + p1 * y[t-1]

With this equation you can get a sense of what happened here:

```
             x     fittedets fittedarima
1  0.000000000 -6.997521e-07 0.000000000
2  0.000000000 -7.065016e-11 0.000000000 # .9219 * 0 = 0
3  0.000000000 -7.133162e-15 0.000000000 # .9219 * 0 = 0
4  0.000000000 -7.201966e-19 0.000000000 # .9219 * 0 = 0
5  0.002177650  0.000000e+00 0.000000000 # .9219 * 0 = 0
6  0.003390327  2.177430e-03 0.002007587 # .9219 * .00217 = .002007
7  0.003573749  3.390205e-03 0.003125561 # .9219 * .00339 = .003125
```

You can also observe this behavior with a plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
fcast <- forecast(auto.arima(tsData), h = 7)

autoplot(fcast) + 
  autolayer(fitted(fcast))
```

[image]

For the ets model a similar thing happens, but I hope this made it clear why `auto.arima` had such result. Next time you could explore more forecasting models that are included in the `forecast` package.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you for this reply.Can I ask then: when the data is plotted as a comparison of fit, it "looks" clearly offset. I get something similar to this with my model, and our business users ask - "surely this should be set back a period". For the purposes of demonstrating model fit, why is the 'fit' not automatically shifted back a period?

Comment: @Jon, for this specific model, the fitted values look offset because of the model. The Arima model fitted is a **(1,  0, 0) model with 0 mean**. Which basically means that the way this model predicts is multiplying the last seen value by it's only estimate, since the estimate is close to 1 (.9219) it basically means that the prediction is **~92%** of the last seen value. Which results in the offset behavior. This is the model that `auto.arima` found best, and it's clearly not the best fit, it's best to try other models and compare their results.

Comment: Lightbulb moment. Thank you. One assumes that a more complex model with (e.g.) MA terms could potentially have a + x% effect which would then push the fit back in line... or not, but it would remove the offset "appearance".